# Moodle Install plugin setting doesn't appear in Site administration

Tags: plugins, moodle

I am a new user of moodle, and I am trying to create a educational platform. I currently using the free version of moodle so I can test the features and after trial period finish buy the license. My problem is that I am trying to upload a theme from plugins, but the "Install plugin" button doesn't appear on the "Site administration". I am the only super admin in the forum. I have seen some similar questions and in most of them the answer was to be sure that you viewing with super admin view (but I am sure that this isn't the problem).

I have hosted this site to moodle official server. After searching and many re-installations of the platform, didn't manage to find out what is wrong.

Does anyone had the same problem and found solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you edit or view `yourmoodlesite/config.php` ?

Does it have one of these settings?

```
$CFG->disableonclickaddoninstall = true;

$CFG->disableupdateautodeploy = true;
```

Either delete them or set to `false`

For more details see `yourmoodlesite/config-dist.php`

New versions of Moodle

```
// Use the following flag to completely disable the installation of plugins
// (new plugins, available updates and missing dependencies) and related
// features (such as cancelling the plugin installation or upgrade) via the
// server administration web interface.
//
//      $CFG->disableupdateautodeploy = true;
```

Old versions of Moodle

```
// Use the following flag to completely disable the On-click add-on installation
// feature and hide it from the server administration UI.
//
//      $CFG->disableonclickaddoninstall = true;
```

Comment: After seeing your answer, and done some more research, I am here to have a kind of "answer" to my past problem. I realized that it is really bad option to host your moodle platform on the moodle servers. It is way more better to host it on any other server provider. With this option, it is way easier to change the core code of your platform. At least that worked perfect for me. I couldn't find the way to edit my files from moodle server. And of course the problem was exactly this line in config file. Thanks a lot!!